# How to rename an attachment when using ArcGIS Collector for Android?

Tags: arcgis-collector, attachments

I am using ArcGIS Collector for Android, v 18.0.3 Build 1033 and I don't see a way to rename attachments in the field.  Is this possible from within the Collector application?  Or do I need to save photos to the device and rename them, and then attachment them to the feature in ArcGIS Collector?

Comment: Download feature service as file gdb, open attachments table and rename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, so I'm answering with some screenshots to assist those who are like myself: fat fingered and digitally uncoordinated.

1. First, you need to be editing the feature (that wasn't my issue but it bears repeating).
2. On the attachment, short tap the text of the attachment.  Not the image because each has its own behavior.
   [image]
3. When short tapping the text of the attachment, the menu will appear and `Rename` is one of them. 
   [image]
4. And now the attachment can be renamed:
   [image]